# How to check if background queries have been completed in Parse.com with Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I need to populate an array with different users' data retrieved from Parse.com. Using `getFirstObject` is apparently not a good idea, but I don't know how to find out when all data have been fetched for every user:

```
    myObjects = []
    for user in users { // users is an array of PFUsers
        let query = PFQuery(className: "MyClass")
        query.whereKey("asdh74tbf", equalTo: user)

        query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{ (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let object = object {
                self.myObjects.append(object)
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to perform `self.tableView.reloadData()`, when all objects have been retrieved. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dispatch groups. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) in the "Waiting on Groups of Queued Tasks" for more information.

Also you mentioned you want to get all objects of every user. So instead of getFirstObject you can use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method. The block returns the parsed response. So combining this and the dispatch groups your code can look something like this

```
//create a new dispatch group
let group: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create();
var myObjects = []
for user in users { // users is an array of PFUsers
    let query = PFQuery(className: "MyClass")
    query.whereKey("asdh74tbf", equalTo: user)

    //enter the dispatch group
    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: NSArray!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let object = object {
            self.myObjects.append(object)
        } else {
            // handle error
        }

        //leave the dispatch group
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }
}

//will be called when all the async operations entered in the group are finished.  
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    });
```